# Numpy: Select elements from arrays where difference between the current and the previous element is small

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have two numpy 1 dimensional arrays `times` and `values` which are both 712 entries long. I want to slice out all entries, barring the first, where the difference between the current time and the previous is smaller than 9.

I have a truth table I want to map onto these two arrays.

```
>>> print((times[1:] - times[:-1]) < 9)
[False False False False False False False False  True False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False  True False False  True False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False  True False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False  True]
```

How do I slice out all elements of times and values where this is True? I was told to use the slicing function of numpy arrays. Example:

```
>>> my_list = np.array([12, 15, 3, 5, 19, 4])
>>> print(my_list[my_list%2 == 0])
[12  4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Stackoverflow is my Rubber Duck apparently.

The numpy slicing already does what I want it to, selecting out the values of a list, where the entry is "True". I just have to slice the original array to length:

```
ntimes = times[1:]
print(ntimes[(times[1:] - times[:-1]) < 9])

nvals = vals[1:]
print(nvals[(times[1:] - times[:-1]) < 9])
```